# spring-kafka - error handling via group rebalance

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm writing a kafka listener which should just forward the messages from a topic to a jms queue. I need to stop processing new messages only for a custom exception `JmsBrokerConnectionException` but i want to continue processing new messages for any other exceptions (ie invalid data) and send error messages to a DLT.
I am using spring-kafka 2.2.7 and cannot upgrade it.

I have currently a solution which uses:

- `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` (configured with 0 retries and a `DeadLetterPubishingRecoverer`)
- a retry template used in the `@KafkaListener` method configured with `Integer.MAX_VALUE` retries, which retries only for `JmsBrokerConnectionException`
- MANUAL_IMMEDIATE ack

The solution seems to do the job but it has the drawback that, for long outages of the jms broker, it would cause a rebalance each `max.poll.interval.ms` (ie 5 mins).

The question:
Is it a good idea to let `max.poll.interval.ms` expire and have a group rebalance to handle error conditions for which you want to stop message consumption?

I don't have high-throughput requirements.
The input topic has 10 partitions and i will have 2 consumers.
I know there are other solutions using stateful retry or pausing/resuming the container, but i'd like to keep using the current solution unless i am missing any major drawbacks about it.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using spring-kafka 2.2.7 and cannot upgrade it.

That version is no longer supported.

Version 2.3 added backoff and exception classification to the STCEH, eliminating the need for a retry template at the listener level.

That said, you can use stateful retry (https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#stateful-retry) with a STCEH that always retries, and do the dead letter publishing in the `RecoveryCallback` at the listener level. The consumer record is available in the retry context with the `RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.CONTEXT_RECORD` key.

Since you are doing manual acks, you will also need to commit the offset via the `CONTEXT_CONSUMER` key.